# how to create mysql table using html form from php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a signup page where if user inserts required details then by clicking on sign up button it should insert details in selected table and create a new table in database too my html code is:

```
  <form method="POST" action="signuplink.php" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-6 justify-content-center form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">first_name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
<div class="col-md-6 justify-content-center form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">last_name</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 justify-content-center form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">phonenumber</label>
    <input type="text" name="phonenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 justify-content-center form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 justify-content-center form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">email </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="username@domain.com">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 justify-content-center form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">password </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="select password">
</div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success ">Signup</button>
</form>
```

php code is as below where i redirected the form kindly help to create new table automatically when user fills up the form successfully :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include 'connection.php';
$x = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['email']);
$firstname= mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['first_name']);
$lastname= mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['last_name']);
$username= mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['username']);
$phonenumber= mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['phonenumber']);
$y= mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['password']);

//Error handlers
//Check for empty fields
if (empty($x) || empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || empty($username) || empty($phonenumber) || empty($y))
{
    header("Location: signup.php?signup=empty");
    exit();
}
    else
{
//Check if input characters are valid
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $firstname) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $lastname))
{
    header("Location: signup.php?signup=invalid");
    exit();
}
else
{
//Check if email is valid
if (!filter_var($x, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
header("Location: signup.php?signup=email");
exit();
}
else
{
$_SESSION['first_name']=$firstname;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' or email='$x'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
header("Location: signup.php?signup=usertaken");
exit();
} else {
//Hashing the password
$hashedPwd = password_hash($y, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
//Insert the user into the database
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (ID, username, phonenumber, email,first_name, last_name, password) VALUES ('','$username', '$phonenumber','$x','$firstname','$lastname','$hashedPwd');";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
header("Location: signup.php?signup=successfully_logged_in");
exit();
}
if($connect->query($sql)===TRUE)
{
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $username (
ID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)";
if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error creating table: " . $connect->error;
}
}
}
}
}


else {
header("Location: signup.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: `CREATE TABLE $username` are you sure you want to do this? It's really not a good idea.

Comment: Are you creating a table for each user? Please, don't. Put all the users in a table instead. Let's think about it this way: why would you ever want to create 1000 tables with one row when you can create 1 table with 1000 rows?

Comment: Check your logic again. Go though your code one step at a time and you'll see why it's failing. I want *you* to think about it and fix it yourself and you will learn from it.

Comment: The security implications here outweigh the benefits

Comment: @Fred-ii- i want to take each user details separate as i am working on ecommerce where each and every customer will have their own orders and carts if you can suggest me some better way to do so then please share the logic will try to do so thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are trying to create an e-commerce backend, you should really not do it from scratch if you're still learning. At least if you're thinking about storing any precious data (email/password combos and credit cards).

As far as a table per user, it is not being efficient with a database. Think differently.

You have:
- customers (users in your case)
- shipping_addresses (you can link these to customers by a `customer_id`)
- carts (again you can link these to customers by `customer_id`)
- orders (... you can link these to customers by `customer_id`)

You just need to insert a new row and depending on the logged in user's `id`, you add that id to the targeted table's `customer_id` field.

Ex. Paul creates a new order.

`$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (id, customer_id, order_number, order_status, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('', '$logged_in_users_id', '$generated_unique_order_number', '$initial_order_status', '$created_at_timestamp', '$updated_at_timestamp');";`

Comment: You can also look at https://www.princeton.edu/~rcurtis/ultradev/images/storediagram.gif for an idea.